# Why are cookies strings and not objects?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to learn all about cookies. From exploring `document.cookie` and associated methods I have learned that getting a cookie is not as simple as it could be. Yes, the function to get and set a cookie is straight forwards enough, but why are cookies strings when it seems that their use would be better served as objects?

For example, getting a cookie requires:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

But if the cookie was an object, could we not just use something like:

```
document.cookie(cookiename)?
```

I know thus must sound too basic to those that follow the js tag. But I'm just trying to understand the choice of using  a string for cookies, since they seem so widely used surely they deserve their own built in js methods for viewing, getting and setting?

Comment: Presumably because nobody has considered it worth the effort of writing a spec and getting all the browser vendors to implement it.

Comment: As Quentin said (more–or–less), because that's what [*RFC 6265 HTTP State Management Mechanism*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) (the specification for cookies) and [*HTML5*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-cookie) says in regard to *document.cookie*: "*On getting…the user agent must first obtain the storage mutex and then return the cookie-string…*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some research and I would like to make a guess.

Cookies were created as a method to make a website remember of some small particular things such a user preference. Specifically they were created when some guy at netscape was working on an e-commerce application in '94. He applied something called "magic cookie" a methodology used often in common programming to the Web ( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_cookie).

Since then the need has always been to store some simple url parameter of the user transaction. The technique as you know was to store a particular simple text file containing the parameters to be remembered. It seems it spread out when Internet Explorer integrated it into its v2 browser.

I guess the combination of:
1. The need of simply storing a few key information about a transaction. 
2. The fact that they were meant to be secure so they could not contain functions or pieces of code of any kind
may have contributed to the non-evolution of the cookie.

There are a lot of things about cookies history just on Wikipedia I suggest you read. I just read them and found them super funny and interesting.

The last thing I would suggest is to get to know cookies as fast as you can and start reading about/studying Localstorage ( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage).

The advantage is that you can use json objects to manage stored data. 
The disadvantage is that there isn't a version of it that shares data with your server (a special type of cookie will do the job anyway).

I hope I had been useful!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll read up on Wikipedia. So because of their implicit need to be secure and thus not contain functions, they did not evolve with the rest of the internet? But, as a learner, if my question valid that cookies would be easier to work with if they were objects?

Comment: I will do more research since your question is keeping me up this night :) anyway I guess if they were objects it would have been much easier to interact with them, set, get and delete data from them

Comment: But I would like you to consider this: if you wrap current cookies into a custom improved system to manage them the thing would be much easier too. For example, I worked on a module for angularjs called Biscotti. It's basically a wrapper for a storage so instead of using that function directly I created an object oriented version of cookies with getters and setters methods. Quite a fun!

Comment: I was thinking that too, but since I'm a little less experienced with JS and code in general, I was wondering if that was a waste of time because maybe there was some unforseens I did not consider. I thought that there must be a reason it's not an object

Comment: Just to add, a colleague at work showed me something using jquery:
$.cookie('cookiename') in the console gets the cookie :-)